# Dotliquid Date Filter

Tags: c#, dotliquid

I am trying to calculate the days between "now" and a provided date. I found a SO post that seems to do exactly what I am looking for.
[Shopify (liquid): Find number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340705/shopify-liquid-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Unfortunately, when i change it for my model I experience problems. After some debugging my guess is it is related to dates with an applied filter, in my situation "minus".

If I do something like:

```
{{"now" | date: "%s" }}
```

I get a valid result. But once i apply a filter to it:

```
{{"now" | date: "%s" | minus: 604800 }}
```

I get "Liquid error: Parameter count mismatch."

I also made sure that it isn't the minus filter, i tried basic math like:

```
{{ 100 | minus : 20 }}
```

and it was successful to print "80".

Is there a setting i am forgetting? I have these settings turned on.

```
Liquid.UseRubyDateFormat = true;
Template.NamingConvention = new DotLiquid.NamingConventions.RubyNamingConvention();
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I were you I would avoid doing computations directly in DotLiquid. Instead make sure you pass it the final form of your data (bar some formatting).

Answer (score 2):

With this, `{{"now" | date: "%s" }}` you were not far from "truth". This is how it works

```
private static void SmallTest()
{
    const string templateString = @"xxx '{{ k1 | Date : ""D""  }}' yyy";
    Template.NamingConvention = new CSharpNamingConvention();
    var t = Template.Parse(templateString);
    string output = t.Render(Hash.FromDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>(){ { "k1", "now" } }));
    Console.WriteLine("NOW --> " + output);
}
```

What I found out, filter `Date` is case sensitive. It doesn't get picked up with `date`.

But I don't think you can do minus on the date. What you need is custom filter

```
public static class TextFilters
{
    public static string DaysFromNow(object input)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(input)).ToString();
    }
}

Template.RegisterFilter(typeof(TextFilters));
```

Usage: `{{ k2 | DaysFromNow }}`
Rendering:

```
Hash.FromDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>(){ { "k2", -10 } }));
```

All code above is tested and working